Google Tag Manager - Get Div instead of Img element
First.. I'm a newbie about GTM.
I want to track a DIV element that is a container for an IMG and another DIV(text).
By using GTM trigger All Clicks > Specific clicks > Click Classes contains > "image-item" it fire me the IMG element inside the DIV with the class I provided. Problem is that when visitor click on the texte instead of the IMG I do not get informations I want.
That's why I need to get the DIV container fired. Someone can help me?
<div class="image-item thumbnail lien" onclick="openGallery('amalia')" data-name="Amalia">
<img src="assets/works/thumbnails/lucienagasse-amalia.jpg" alt="Amalia" />
<div class="cascade"><b>Amalia</b></div>
</div>

